# presentModalView not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my view controller, I have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

        LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        lvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];
        [lvc release];

}
```

However, this doesn't show up. What might be the possibilities? I tried to do a NSLog inside and it prints out.

Here's how I wire it up:

[image]

This is a UISplitView application where I put this code inside a RootViewController

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController); , if nil, then there is a bigger problem at hand.

Comment: I got <UINavigationController: 0x5d231e0>, so it's not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have a conflicting code in my UIDetailView, which is trying to do another popup...

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the View to the LoginViewController in IB? That's the most common issue...

Comment: Did you declared the corresponding XIB in your class? Maybe you try LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNib.xib" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

If logging your navigationController does not give you nil, then try the following:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating your LoginViewController correctly.  Try replacing:

```
LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
```

with

```
LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
```

You need to specify which NIB to load the view controller from.

Comment: your suggestion is the same as suggested below.. it didn't work